# Solr Replication without using zookeeper

Tags: load-balancing, high-availability, solr

The application that I am currently working on does not need real time indexing. I am using Solr as the indexing engine and I want to setup a High Availability Solr cluster with 2 replica nodes. Seems zookeeper can be of help, but again, to make it HA i need to spend some infrastructure for zookeeper replication itself. The budget constraint makes me think of an alternative solution.

As my application does not need real time indexing, I am thinking of developing a daemon  which can keep a queue of indexing data and post it to both the instances of solr. To provide load balancing & failover, I will use the same HAProxy load balancer that I am using for my current Application servers.

Does this configuration makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the legacy replication handler to do your replication.
No need for your own daemon, send updates to one server and let Solr handle replication to the other. You can use your HAProxy to send requests between your master and the slave.